# How to pass a value to a collection by reference

Tags: c#, .net

Is there by chance any collection in .NET that would allow me to pass multiple values by reference. This implies that if I were to modify an item's value in an  array for instance, my original item would be altered too. This snippet should make things more clear.

```
string str1 = null, str2 = null // ...
var arr1 = new string[] { str1, str2 }; // pass by reference
var arr2 = new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
for (int i = 0; i < arr2.Count(); i++)
    arr1[i] = arr2[i]; // assign new value
Console.WriteLine($"{str1} {str2}"); 
// output: value1 value2
```

An alternative solution could be to access the items using a *dynamic* name (since all strings share the same prefix "str..."). This, however, doesn't seem achievable to me in any short, let elegant way. *The following snippet is but a mere example to detail further.*

```
string str1 = null, str2 = null // ...
var arr = new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count(); i++)
    str[i] = arr[i]; // access using a "dynamic" name
Console.WriteLine($"{str1} {str2}");
// output: value1 value2
```

**EDIT**

After the answers I got it became clear to me this wasn't possible. I am stuck right now since `str1` and `str2` are in fact ***out parameters***; therefore, I can't create new variables.

Comment: consider using a dictionary. .net's pointers are really complicated and would be one way to do it, but you have to work around the GC.

Comment: No. That would imply you are passing in the pointer of field that points to that object, this can't be done.

Comment: If you make an object and pass it in then yes it's by reference.  Instead of just a string wrap it in a class ```Person.Name```  Then when you change the Name it will change by reference.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII No, that's *not* passing a parameter by reference.  It's passing a parameter by value where that value happens to be a reference.  It may allow the OP to solve their problem, but it wouldn't be passing the value by reference.

Comment: @Servy No where does he mention parameters by reference. It does solve his problem. And this line he wrote alone says he wants just that to happen ```var arr1 = new string[] { str1, str2 }; // pass by reference```

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Yes, he wants to pass those values by reference.  I'm saying your suggestion wouldn't do that.  Your suggestion would involve passing a reference type by value, not passing whatever the type is by reference.  The semantics are different.  It may be a suitable way for the OP to solve their problem anyway, but what you suggested isn't actually what they asked for, precisely because your proposal *wouldn't* be passing those variables by reference.  We don't have enough information to know if the semantic differences between those two are important to the OP.

Comment: @Servy  Ok, I'll bite that but it's as close as he's gonna get without an custom object that stores collections and he (by the examples) just needs to know how to pass an object. So instead of going on a 10 mile walk to explain the complete in's and out's of ref and reference types mutability etc just show him how to make an object and how it passes by reference.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII The question is *specifically* asking for a different type of collection that uses reference semantics, rather than value semantics, so from the question they appear to be quite aware that they're going to need a different type of collection.  Again, what you're proposing is different than what's being asked for.  Whether it's close enough to meet their needs is not something we could say from the information in the question, whether the drawbacks of your proposal are a problem for their actual situation isn't something we can know.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII "just show him how to make an object and how it passes by reference" Once again, *that is not passing things by reference*.  That's what the question asks for, and *that is not what your proposal accomplishes*.  It does something similar, but still distinctly different, which is passing reference types by value.  The differences may well be important for the OP's actual situation, without knowing what it is we can't know.

Comment: @Servy We can know because we've tutored enough developers in their early stages to realize that like us, they get the wording or questions wrong but have the right intentions; and through it we know what their asking for. I have given answers to questions that were direct, as a joke even, but I never argued with someone that was on the right path of helping them. Simply put, if the guy isn't new to development he'll correct me, it's his question, but for you to piggy back on a 'comment' and tell me how my semantics are wrong (even though you're technically right) is just a poot in the wind.

Comment: So seemingly, this isn't possible. I am stuck right now, since I don't have any alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

No. That would imply you are passing in the pointer of field that points to that object, this can't be done. Take your collection/array out the picture and consider 2 variables in this scenario and you can see how it works and how the behavior would not be any different if you tried to use an array instead.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo1 = new Foo(){Name = "Test"};
        var foo2 = foo1;
        // at this point both foo1 and foo2 are pointers to the same location in memory 

        // test
        Console.WriteLine("foo1.Name = " + foo1.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("foo2.Name = " + foo2.Name);

        // reassign the pointer for foo1
        Reassign(ref foo1);

        // at this point foo1 has been reassigned to a new location in memory, foo2 remains unchanged and still points to the original object in memory created earlier
        Console.WriteLine("foo1.Name = " + foo1.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("foo2.Name = " + foo2.Name);
    }


    public static void Reassign(ref Foo f)
    {
        // at this point you are reassigning exactly 1 pointer
        f = new Foo()
        {
            Name = System.DateTime.Now.ToString()
        };
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible only if you use mutable types. It won't work with strings because they are immutable (they can't be changed after they're created).

If, for example, instead of an array of `string` types, you used a class that has a string property, your sample would look like:

```
class StringWrapper
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

private static void Main()
{
    StringWrapper str1 = new StringWrapper {Value = null};
    StringWrapper str2 = new StringWrapper {Value = null};

    var arr1 = new[] { str1, str2 }; // pass by reference
    var arr2 = new[]
    {
        new StringWrapper {Value = "value1"},
        new StringWrapper {Value = "value2"}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.Count(); i++)
        arr1[i].Value = arr2[i].Value; // assign new value

    Console.WriteLine($"{str1.Value} {str2.Value}");

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: "It's possible only if you use reference types"  `string` is a reference type already.  It's a *mutable* type that they would need.